# Returning true or error message in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering if writing functions like this is considered good or bad form.

```
def test(x)
    if x == 1
        return true
    else
        return "Error: x is not equal to one."
    end
end
```

And then to use it we do something like this:

```
result = test(1)

if result != true
    puts result
end

result = test(2)

if result != true
    puts result
end
```

Which just displays the error message for the second call to test.

I'm considering doing this because in a rails project I'm working on inside my controller code I make calls to a model's instance methods and if something goes wrong I want the model to return the error message to the controller and the controller takes that error message and puts it in the flash and redirects. Kinda like this

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    if !@item.nil?
        result = @item.save_image(params[:attachment][:file])

        if result != true
            flash[:notice] = result

            redirect_to(new_item_url) and return
        end

        #and so on...
```

That way I'm not constructing the error messages in the controller, merely passing them along, because I really don't want the controller to be concerned with what the save_image method itself does just whether or not it worked.

It makes sense to me, but I'm curious as to whether or not this is considered a good or bad way of writing methods. Keep in mind I'm asking this in the most general sense pertaining mostly to ruby, it just happens that I'm doing this in a rails project, the actual logic of the controller really isn't my concern.

Comment: Ruby usually uses 2 spaces to indent, not 4.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would say that methods that return different types (e.g. boolean vs. string vs. numbers) under different circumstances are a bad practice.

If you have some sort of test method that wants to return details of why the test has not passed then you can return a pair of values (an `Array`) as follows:

```
def test(x)
    if x == 1
        return true, "x is fine"
    else
        return false, "Error: x is not equal to one."
    end
end
```

and then write the section of your controller code as:

```
valid, message = @item.save_image(params[:attachment][:file])

if !valid
  flash[:notice] = message
  redirect_to(new_item_url) and return
end
```

If you're talking about a `save_image` method that will succeed the majority of the time but may fail and you want to indicate this failure and the reason then I would use [exceptions](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Exception.html) e.g.

```
def save_image(file)
  raise "No file was specified for saving" if file.nil? 
  # carry on trying to save image
end
```

and then your controller code would be along the lines of:

```
begin
  result = @item.save_image(params[:attachment][:file])
rescue Exception => ex
  flash[:notice] = ex.message
  redirect_to(new_item_url) and return
end
```

Comment: That's actually a much better idea. The reason I was even wondering if this was good or bad practice was because different data types could be returned. That's not a huge deal since Ruby is flexible like that, but from the standpoint of clean, understandable, and maintainable code it just bugged me.

Comment: I definitely like the exceptions. The first solution i do not like. It is very clean code, but i don't like the fact that a function is also concerned about the error-message which needs to be sent to the user. In a I18n situation this would completely mess up :)

Comment: This is definitely an improvement from the methods in the question, but forgive me for still not being satisfied. The first method has a clunky 2 variables coming from the call, and to check for success requires multiple lines. The second method would put lots of exceptions and begin/rescues all over my app. Smells bad. I want to do something like this: render item.errors unless item.validate_x_y_z. Is that possible?

Comment: @TheJKFever to check for success using the first method, you need only one line: `test(foo)[0]`.