# get each individual number from a Fixnum integer Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a real ultra newbie question.

I have an age stored in a database.

When I get the age from the database I want to get each individual digit.

Example:

```
User.age = 25
```

I want to get the following:

```
first = 5
second = 2
```

I can't seem to wrestle this from the data as its a fix num.

Anyone know a clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can convert to a string and then split into digits e.g.

```
first, second = User.age.to_s.split('')
=> ["2", "5"]
```

If you need the individual digits back as Fixnums you can map them back e.g.

```
first, second = User.age.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }
=> [2, 5]
```

Alternatively, you can use integer division e.g.

```
first, second = User.age.div(10), User.age % 10
=> [2, 5]
```

Note that the above examples are using [parallel assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895957/parallel-assignment-operator-in-ruby/2895989#2895989) that you might not have come across yet if you're new to Ruby.

Comment: `map { |digit| digit.to_i }` shortcut => `map(&:to_i)`

Comment: Also: `n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: In your case, you can also use the divmod method.
I prefer the Integer#digits method btw, `1234.digits    # => [4, 3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 11):

Ruby 2.4 has [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_rc1/Integer.html#method-i-digits) method. eg:

```
25.digits
# => [5, 2]
```

So you can do

```
first, second = user.age.digits
```

Comment: Perfect, best solution for now

Comment: Note it returns the digits in 'reverse' order, meaning from the number 25, the 0th digit returned in the array is 5, not 2

Answer (score 7):

```
first, last = User.age.divmod(10)
```

Comment: this doesn't return the first digit if the users age has three digits

Answer (score 4):

Check out benchmarks for a lot of solutions here: http://gistflow.com/posts/873-integer-to-array-of-digits-with-ruby The best one is to use `divmod` in a loop:

```
def digits(base)
  digits = []

  while base != 0 do
    base, last_digit = base.divmod(10)
    digits << last_digit
  end

  digits.reverse
end
```

Comment: Nice, but as a general purpose method, this has a flaw: It will return `[]` for `0`. This can be fixed by replacing `while base != 0` with `loop`, and adding `return digits.reverse if base == 0` to the bottom of that loop, instead of the return value outside the loop. It will still however loop infinitely for negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001210

```
 25.to_s.each_char {|c| print c, ' ' }
```

This stuff is really easy to find through Ruby docs.

Comment: I was converting to a string and then used the string[0].chr.  I thought that there must be a better way.  That divmod(10) is pretty cool and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but just for collection:

```
User.age.chars.to_a.map(&:to_i)
#=> [5, 2]
first, second = User.age.chars.to_a.map(&:to_i)
```