# Why doesn't assigning a variable to an array yield expected results in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, variable-assignment, irb

Using IRB, I tested the following:

```
C:\Pickaxe>irb
irb(main):001:0> list_of_strings = %w{ a list of strings in an array }
=> ["a", "list", "of", "strings", "in", "an", "array"]
irb(main):002:0> a, b, c = list_of_strings
=> ["a", "list", "of", "strings", "in", "an", "array"]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> "a"
irb(main):004:0> b
=> "list"
irb(main):005:0> c
=> "of"
irb(main):006:0>
```

In the other languages I've developed in setting `a, b, c = d` sets the values of `a`, `b` and `c` to equal `d` in its entirety. Here they are set to successive elements in the array.

I don't understand how or why this works. Could someone shed light on the issue?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895957/parallel-assignment-operator-in-ruby) answer.

Comment: Ahh, thank you Squiguy. Is there a way I could assign the values of a, b, and c to the whole array without having to do it on multiple lines?

Comment: Do you mean something like `a = b = c = list_of_strings`?

Comment: Ahh, see that'd work :) Thanks

Comment: Ruby is a little different. I mean the language always brags that it does "what makes sense to the programmer."

Comment: @squiguy: Destructuring bind in Ruby works pretty much exactly how it works in every other language. Not sure what's so different about that.

Comment: @squiguy, "I mean the language always brags that it does 'what makes sense to the programmer.'" Matz, says "[The principle of least surprise means principle of least my surprise. And it means the principle of least surprise after you learn Ruby very well.](http://www.artima.com/intv/rubyP.html)" Personally, after many other languages, I find Ruby to be very intuitive *when* I stop to think about what I'm doing. Being human I sometimes *don't* do that, which is when I am surprised.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Am I not asking questions properly? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how array assignment works in Ruby. It's trying to be clever, a little, by assigning each indexed item of the array to that variable on the left-hand side of the assignment `=`

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be surprising. Perl does the same thing, and it's been around for years and years, and it's very much a mainstream language.