# Ruby x,y = gets.split.map &:to_i

Tags: ruby

I am confused about this line of ruby code.
Why is the assignment given to x, y and not a single variable?

```
x,y = gets.split.map &:to_i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assigns the first entry from the array to `x`, and the second entry to `y` in contrast to assigning to a single variable in which case the array would be assigned to that variable.

Putting multiple variables on the left hand side of an assignment is a way of unpacking an array into separate variables. You can try this in irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> first, second = numbers
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):003:0> first
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> second
=> 2
```

Check out [this answer to an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895957/parallel-assignment-operator-in-ruby/2895989#2895989) that I wrote which gives some more details and is a good example of where this can be useful.

Comment: Awesome thanks for answer and the link. It helped alot!