# Ruby Syntax Explanation

Tags: ruby

I was reading through the documentation for [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) and I ran across this example:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end
```

Everything makes sense to me except for this line: `a, b = b, a + b`. Could somebody please explain what's happening?

Comment: `a = b` and `b = a + b`.

Comment: Might help if you mentally add brackets: `(a, b) = [b, a + b]` (that syntax also works)

Comment: @NeilSlater Yep! That makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It's a parallel assignment pattern which you can see in many languages including ruby
probably you will find this helpful
[Parallel Assignment operator in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895957/parallel-assignment-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks!