# Is it possible to use parallel assignment for keys in Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, multiple-assignment

Given that it is an immutable object, ruby allows paraller assignments as this:

```
sample[:alpha] = sample[:beta] = sample[:gamma] = 0
```

But is there any other simple way to do this? , something like :

```
sample[alpha:, beta:, gamma: => 0]
```

or:

```
sample[:alpha, :beta, :gamma] => 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: How many keys do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this does not work as you expect:

```
sample = {}
sample[:alpha], sample[:beta], sample[:gamma] = 0
```

This will result in:

```
sample == { alpha: 0, beta: nil, gamma: nil }
```

To get the desired result, you could instead use [parallel assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895989/1954610):

```
sample[:alpha], sample[:beta], sample[:gamma] = 0, 0, 0
```

Or, [loop through the keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) to assign each one separately:

```
[:alpha, :beta, :gamma].each { |key| sample[key] = 0 }
```

Or, [merge](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!) the original hash with your new attributes:

```
sample.merge!(alpha: 0, beta: 0, gamma: 0)
```

---

Depending on what you're actually trying to do here, you may wish to consider giving your hash a [default value](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new). For example:

```
sample = Hash.new(0)

puts sample[:alpha] # => 0
sample[:beta] += 1  # Valid since this defaults to 0, not nil

puts sample         # => {:beta=>1}
```

Comment: Since `0` is immutable, it's safe to use `Hash.new(0)`

Comment: Ah yep, I forgot that's valid too. Thanks @Stefan, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
sample.merge!(alpha: 0, beta: 0, gamma: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like the thing you've described but you can run a loop with all the and assign the value.

```
keys = [:alpha, :beta, :gamma, :theta, ...]
keys.each {|key| sample[key] = 0}
```

Reduces the number of extra keystrokes, and very easy to change the keys array.