# Rails how to return object/true or false with errors redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In designing rails apps I frequently come across the need to call a function that returns true or returns the error message as to why it failed. I've seen many ways to do this but I'm curious what is a good approach. Here are a couple examples of what I might use and their pros and cons. Please respond with what you would consider a good approach and why?

```
# PROS:
# not returning multiple objects
# syntax looks good with if !valid
# uses activerecord style errors
# not interupting program with Exceptions
#
# CONS:
# must know path in advance
# could be sending many errors
#
if (!object.validate_something)
  respond_to |format|
    format.html redirect_to place_to_redirect_to_path, notice:/alert: object.errors.full_messages, status: :some_status_code
    format.json render json: { error: object.errors }, status: :some_status_code, location: place_to_redirect_to_path
  end
end

# PROS:
# dynamic redirect path
# not interupting program with Exceptions
# guarenteed single error if desirable
#
# CONS:
# returning multiple objects
#
path, error = object.validate_something
if (error)
  respond_to |format|
    format.html redirect_to path, notice:/alert: error, status: :some_status_code
    format.json render json: { error: error }, status: :some_status_code, location: path
  end
end

# PROS:
# uses activerecord style errors
#
# CONS:
# not very readable
# returns object or false
# must know path
#
if (response = validate_something)
  # do something with response
else
  respond_to |format|
    format.html redirect_to place_to_redirect_to_path, notice:/alert: object.errors.full_messages, status: :some_status_code
    format.json render json: { error: object.errors }, status: :some_status_code, location: place_to_redirect_to_path
  end
end
```

Here is a similar post but doesn't quite answer the question [Returning true or error message in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793495/returning-true-or-error-message-in-ruby)